# Should a library function be suspend or return deferred

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Let's assume I'm writing a library that returns a string which is a complex and long running task.

I can chose between offering this

```
interface StringGenerator {
   suspend fun generateString(): String
}
```

or

```
interface StringGenerator {
   fun generateString(): Deferred<String>
}
```

Are there any (dis-)advantages of either of the options and which are they? Which should I choose?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Kotlin coroutines are designed along the ["sequential by default"](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html#sequential-by-default) guideline. That means that your API should always expose `suspend fun`s and the user, if and when they really need it, can easily wrap them in `async`.

The advantage of that is analogous to the advantages of *cold* flows with respect to *hot* flows: a suspendable function is active only while control is inside it. When it returns, it has not left behind a task running in the background.

Whenever you return a `Deferred`, the user must start worrying what happens if they don't manage to await on the result. Some code paths may ignore it, the calling code may get an exception, and then their application has a leak.