# How to correctly use suspend functions with coroutines on webflux?

Tags: reactive-programming, spring-webflux, kotlin-coroutines

I'm new to reactive programming and because I've already used kotlin with `spring-web` in the past, I decided to go to `spring-webflux` on this new project I'm working on. Then I discovered `Mono` and `Flux` apis and decided to use `spring-data-r2dbc`  to keep full reactive stack (I'm aware I don't know how far this new project could be from meeting all reactive expectations, I'm doing this to learn a new tool, not because this is the perfect scenario for this new tool)

then I noticed I could replace all reactive streams apis from webflux with kotlin's native coroutines. I also opted by coroutines simply to learn and have less 'external frameworky' code

my application is quite simple (it's an url shortener):

```
1. parse some url out of http request's body into 3 parts
2. exchange each part to its postgres id on each respective table
3. concat these 3 ids into a new url, sending an 200 http response with this new url
```

my reactive controller is

```
@Configuration
class UrlRouter {

    @Bean
    fun urlRoutes(
        urlHandler: UrlHandler,
        redirectHandler: RedirectHandler
    ) = coRouter {
        POST("/e", urlHandler::encode)
        GET("/{*url}", redirectHandler::redirect)
    }
}
```

as you can imagine, `UrlHandler` is responsible for the steps numbered above and `RedirectHandler` does the oposite: receiving an encoded url, it redirects to the right url received on number 1.

**question 1:** checking on `coRouter`, I assumed that for each http call, spring will start a new coroutine to resolve that call(oposing to a new thread on traditional `spring-web`), and each of these can create and depend on several other sub coroutines. Is this right? Does this hierarchy exist?

here's my `UrlHandler` fragment:

```
@Component
class UrlHandler(
    private val cache: CacheService,
    @Value("\${redirect-url-prefix}") private val prefix: String
) {

    companion object {
        val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
    }

    suspend fun encode(serverRequest: ServerRequest): ServerResponse =
        try {
            val bodyMap: Map<String, String> = mapper.readValue(serverRequest.awaitBody<String>())
            // parseUrl being a string extension function just splitting 
            // that could throw IndexOutOfBoundsException
            val (host, path, query) = bodyMap["url"]!!.parseUrl()

            val hostId: Long = cache.findIdFromHost(host)
            val pathId: Long? = cache.findIdFromPath(path)
            val queryId: Long? = cache.findIdFromQuery(query)

            val encodedUrl = "$prefix/${someOmmitedStringConcatenation(hostId, pathId, queryId)}"
            ok().bodyValueAndAwait(mapOf("url" to encodedUrl))
        } catch (e: IndexOutOfBoundsException) {
            ServerResponse.badRequest().buildAndAwait()
        }
```

all three `findIdFrom***` calls try to retrieve an existing id and if it doesn't exist, save new entity and return new id from postgres sequence. This is done by `CoroutineCrudRepository` interfaces. Since my [methods should always suspend](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60448871/3026886), all 3 `findIdFrom***` also `suspend`:

```
@Repository
interface HostUrlRepo : CoroutineCrudRepository<HostUrl, Long> {
    suspend fun findByHost(host: String): HostUrl?
}
```

**question 2:** looking [here](https://spring.io/blog/2020/05/18/what-s-new-in-spring-data-klara-dan-von-neumann) I've found `either invoke reactive query methods or have native suspended functions`. Since I've read `methods should always suspend`, I've decided to keep myself using `suspend`. Is this bad/wrong in any way?

these 3 `findIdFrom***` are independent and could be called to run in parallel and then only at `someOmmitedStringConcatenation` I should wait for any unfinished calls to actually build my encoded url

**question 3:** since every single method has the `suspend` modifier, it will run exactly as on traditional imperative sequential paradigm (wasting any benefit from parallel programming) ?

**question 4:** is this a valid scenario for coroutines usage? If so, how should I change my code to best fit the parallelism I want above?

*possible solutions I've found for question 4:*

**question 4.1:** [source 1](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/kotlin-coroutines-reactive-streams/) inside each `findIdFrom***` wrap it with `withContext(Dispatchers.IO){ /*actual code here*/ }` and then on `encode` function:

```
coroutineScope {
    val hostIdDeferred = async { findIdFrom***() }
    val pathIdDeferred = async { findIdFrom***() }
    val queryIdDeferred = async { findIdFrom***() }
}
```

and when I want to use them, just use `hostIdDeferred.await()` to get the value. If I'm using `Dispatchers.IO` scope to run code inside new children coroutines, why `coroutineScope` is necessary? Is this the correct way, specifying a scope to the new coroutine child and then using `coroutineScope` to have a deferred val?

**question 4.2:** [source 2](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/launch-vs-async-in-kotlin-coroutines/) `val resultOne = Async(Dispatchers.IO) { function1() }` Intellij wasn't able to recognize/import any `Async` expression. How can I use this one and how it differs from previous one?

I'm open to improve and clarify any point on this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to answer some of your questions:

- q2: No, nothing wrong with it. Suspend methods can propagate all the way back to a controller. If your controllers are reactive, i.e. if you use RSocket with `org.springframework.messaging.handler.annotation.MessageMapping`, then even even controller methods can be suspend.
- q3: right, but each method is still  your source code is much simpler
- q4.2: I wouldn't consider that website as a trustworthy source. There is an official documentation with examples: [async](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/async.html)